# EF 6.4 SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table PERMISSION'; column does not allow NULLS

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I am inserting into my applied permission table which is the relation between Groups, ApplicationResources and Permissions

As you can see my object has no nulls

yes when I save  I get Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table  PERMISSION'; column does not allow NULLS

I am confused

```
public TEntity Save(TEntity obj)
{
    try
    {

        lock (obj)
        {
            _context.Entry(obj).State = obj.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _context.Entry(obj).Reload();

        }

        return obj;


    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //return null;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong algorithm. You can' t use the same algorithm for update and add new item. For example I use these generic methods:

```
public virtual T Add(T t)
        {

            Context.Set<T>().Add(t);
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return t;
        }

public virtual T Update(T t)
        {
            if (t == null) return null;
            var exist = Context.Set<T>().Find(t);
            if (exist == null) return exist;
            Context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
            Context.SaveChanges();

            return exist;
        }
```

As you can see Context.Entry(exist) should be used to update, not to add new. This is why you have the error.

And what are you using Lock for? EF tracking queries if you like it or not. If you want to run another task in the same time you will have to create an new db context.

Comment: save method is working fine for close to 6 other entities

Comment: It is always working fine for 99 cases from 100. But you can't  make an application that will fail from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

so I was using a Permission entity from another object.
We have a table that has all the ApplicationResources and permissions
think of it as a template table

I was using the permission and resource from this.

instead of pulling from the database
this caused the confusion

Below are the changes that made the code work

```
ap = new AppliedPermission();
                    ap.ActiveFlag = true;

                    ap.Version = ap.Version + 1;
                    ap.LastModifiedBy = currentUserId;
                    ap.CreatedBy = currentUserId;
                    ap.CreatedTimestamp = currentTime;
                    ap.ResourceId = uploaded.ResourceId;
                    ap.PermissionId = uploaded.PermissionId;
                    ap.LastModifiedByUser = this.CurrentUser;
                    ap.CreatedByUser = this.CurrentUser;
                    ***ap.LuResource = resRepo.GetById(uploaded.ResourceId);
                    ap.LuPermission = permRepo.GetById(uploaded.PermissionId);
                    ap.UpdatedTimestamp = currentTime;***

                    ap.GroupId = BO.Id;
                    ap.RapidGroup = BO;


                    applPermRepo.Save(ap);
```